# If every open cover of a set $F\in\mathbb{R}$ admits a finite subcover, then $F$ is closed and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This should be a pretty known proof in analysis for many of you but I've (I think) proved it in a different way than I've seen in any textbook.

The bounded proof is pretty straightforward and I proved it in a similar way to what Abbott does on Understanding Analysis. Let $\mathcal{C}=\cup_{x\in F}\, I_x$ be an open cover of $F\in\mathbb{R}$, where $I_x = V_1(x)$ for $x\in F$ ($V_1(x)$ means open ball of radius $1$ with center $x$). By hypothesis, there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal{C}_1 \subset \mathcal{C}$ of $F$. $\mathcal{C_1}$ is bounded, so $F$ has to be bounded as well.

Now for the closed part, which is what's different from what I've seen. Suppose instead that $F$ is not closed and let's prove that there exists an open cover of $F$ that does not admit a finite subcover. Let $\mathcal{C}=\cup_{k=1}^\infty\, I_k$, where $I_k = (\inf F + \frac1k, \sup F - \frac1k)$. This is an open cover of $F$ that does not admit a finite subcover, so we should be done here... perhaps?

Comment: What if $F = [0, 1) \cup (2, 3]$? Then the sets $(\inf F + \tfrac{1}{k}, \sup F - \tfrac{1}{k})$ would not cover $F$.

Comment: Why not for the first part, picking i.e. $\mathcal{C}=I_0\cup I_{1/2}\cup I_{5/2}\cup I_3$ would work. For the last, you're correct that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Let $F$ be the set of irrational numbers between $0$ and $1$, and include $0$ and $1$.  I don't think your proof works.

Comment: What you suggest does not work. Your family may fail to cover $F$.

Comment: It seems you believe that if $F$ is not closed then it does not contain its infimum and its supremum. But this is usually false.

Comment: The set in the first comment be an example of that, right?

Comment: Your proof has a flaw that it does not use the hypothesis that $F$ is not closed. You can say that $F$ is not closed so there is a limit point $c$ which is not in $F$. Replace the $\inf F$ of your argument with $c$ and try with $I_k=\mathbb{R} \setminus [c-1/k,c+1/k]$.

Comment: Astly: I'm not sure what you meant by writing that my book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis (http://measure.axler.net/) does not mention the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. There is a subsection of Section E of the Appendix titled "Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem".

Comment: You are correct, no clue how I missed that since it even has its own bookmark. Thanks for the great book!

Comment: By the way, I especially enjoyed exercise 13 of the same chapter (2A). Very sneaky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\overline{F}$ be the closure of $F$.  If $F$ is not closed, then $\exists x \in \overline{F} \setminus F$.  Define $U_n= \{ y~|~d(x, y) \gt \frac 1n \} $.  Then $x \notin F \Rightarrow F \subseteq \bigcup_n U_n$ and $x \in \overline{F} \Rightarrow \forall n \exists y \in F \text{ such that } d(x, y) \lt \frac 1n $, so $ \{ U_n~|~n \in \Bbb N \} $ is an open cover of $F$ with no finite subcover.  Notice that this proof works in any metric space with the metric topology.

I think that's the concept you're trying to get at, but you don't know that $\inf(f) \notin F$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much better than Abbott's proof.

Comment: @AstlyDichrar My pleasure.  If you found it helpful, an "acceptance" as well as an upvote are always appreciated.